# AngularJs directive - bind child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

**Directive**

```
app.directive('mcAvatar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            width: '=width',
            src: '@src'
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/mc-avatar/mc-avatar.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element[0])
        }
    };
});
```

**Template**

`<img width="{{ width }}" src="{{ src }}" alt="" class="mc-avatar-round">`

**Usage**

`<mc-avatar width="50" src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/cats"></mc-avatar>`

The `element` inside the link function in the directive returns :

```
<mc-avatar width="50" src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/cats" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <img width="50" src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/cats" alt="" class="mc-avatar-round">
</mc-avatar>
```

which gives the the context to `mg-avatar` only. How do I access the `img` element here so that I could use `bind` functions?

Comment: How about `console.log(angular.element(element.children()[0]))` ?

Comment: @DavidR it returns the img element, but I cannot use `bind` :/ `element.children()[0].bind is not a function`

Comment: try `replace: true` option

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx In that case, can you try `element.find("img");` and then try setting your `bind` over it?

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx In either case, store it in a `var` and then try your `bind` statement

Comment: @Sravan - generated a error

@DavidR `element.find("img");` did work thanks :) Can you post your answer so others will benefit from it in the future?  Thanks.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx Just did it.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.find("img");` in your `directive` and then use the `.bind` statement over it to attach events.

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your required code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<mc-avatar width="50" src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/cats"></mc-avatar>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive('mcAvatar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            width: '=width',
            src: '@src'
        },
        
        template: '<img width="{{ width }}" src="{{ src }}" alt="" class="mc-avatar-round">',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element.find("img"))
        }
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the snippet.**

[**Here is a working Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yzoDrefqdzWI4Hjk4aal?p=preview)